# importing tastypie to project

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am learning how to use `tastypie` and I installed it with the command `sudo pip install django-tastypie`.

I wanted to try it out with:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.resources import ALL
from models import Article
```

However I get:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/username/Development/django_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/Users/username/Development/django_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  318.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Users/username/Development/django_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  346.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Users/username/Development/django_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  341.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Users/username/Development/django_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/Users/username/Development/django_tutorial/bin/django_test/django_test/urls.py" in <module>
  14.     (r'^articles/', include('article.urls')),     # links to article/urls
File "/Users/username/Development/django_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  26.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/Users/username/Development/django_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/Users/username/Development/django_tutorial/bin/django_test/article/urls.py" in <module>
  4. from api import ArticleResource
File "/Users/username/Development/django_tutorial/bin/django_test/article/api.py" in <module>
  1. from tastypie.resources import ModelResource

Exception Type: ImportError at /articles/api/article/
Exception Value: No module named tastypie.resources
```

Comment: did u added the tastypie in django installed apps at settings.py

Comment: i did not. I am following a tutorial and that step was skipped. What would I add intp my installed apps?

Comment: add tastypie, in installed app of setting.py http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#configuration

Comment: it actually didnt work

Comment: @SundarNataraj i get this error now and my server wont run http://dpaste.com/1796131/

Comment: hey r u in virtual env

Comment: chk this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255537/django-tastypie-resources-import-error

Comment: @SundarNataraj I thought I was but i just tried it again and I guess i wasn't. Thanks for the help! it worked! You can answer thsi question and Ill gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be two things u probably forget :

1) add `tastypie` into your installed apps in `setting.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    .....
    'tastypie',


)
```

or 
2) U might have installed the tastypie outside the `env` ..