# Import Django settings from external script

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a python script within my Django project designed to run seperate from the Django app. I want to use the settings.py on my Django App how can I do that.

When I try to import

```
from django.conf import settings
```

i get

```
ImportError: No module named DjangoTastypie.settings
```

My project Structure

[image]

I am running using eclipse-> Run as python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [importing tastypie to project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285808/importing-tastypie-to-project)

Comment: Can you add your project structure? And how you are running your script?

Comment: try running `python myscript.py`

Comment: Get the same error

Comment: Looks like your project is not in your `PYTHONPATH`. And I don't see your script in your project.

Comment: Hi the script is on tests.py, And I think the project is on the python path. Everything else ( including the Django and tastypie projects) work fine

Comment: Maybe you should consider writing django command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage

So you basically will need to put this at the beginning of your script

```
import os
import django
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
django.setup()
```

Comment: Hi I get the same error. `import os
import django
from django.conf import settings

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'DjangoTastypie.settings'
django.setup()`  and I get `ImportError: No module named DjangoTastypie.settings`

Answer (score 5):

Based on @Sardorbek Imomaliev, you should also make your DjangoTastypie in your PYTHONPATH, you can do this in your script.

```
import os
import sys
import django
from django.conf import settings

sys.path.append("path/to/DjangoTastypie")  # path to the parent dir of DjangoTastypie
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
django.setup()
```