# variable in setting file using in template

Tags: django, django-templates

everybody! I want to access to constants value that I declare in my setting.py file to use in my template, but not in a template inside the app, I just want to use in my home template the template that I declare in my setting file.

```
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('page.html', 'Page'),
    ('feature.html', 'Page with Feature'),
    ('homeTemplate.html', 'Home Template') // I want to use here
)
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433162/can-i-access-constants-in-settings-py-from-templates-in-django) example about the same problem in StackOverflow, but all case uses the variable inside apps not in top level.

How is the best way to use this value inside this template!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by asking - why do you want to do that? It seems like an odd way of... *adjusting the templates directories that you're using, i guess?*?

[I wonder if you may have an XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) If you post what you're trying to achieve, that might be better than a specific solution to this specific problem.

Broadly though, you can only serve django variables (including from `settings.py`) inside a project or script that's using Django, or at least its environments.  Doing `from django.conf import settings` imports the settings that are available at the highest level in the project, across all of the apps. Projects are laid out in this rough fashion.

```
myproject - 
    - myapp1 
    - myapp2 
    - myproject 
        - settings.py
        - wsgi.py 
    - manage.py
```

As in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196334/import-django-settings-from-external-script), For external scripts, y[ou can still import the django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) thus:

```
import os
import django
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
django.setup()
# now you can use settings.VARIABLE_NAME
```

But: this still won't get it into a template, because getting the variable from here into a template needs you to use the django engine to `render` a response.

If it's not being served by the django system, *it's not a template, it's just a regular html file.*

If it's a template in *another* app in your overall project, you would pass it as part of your context dictionary, [as laid out in the docs on templates.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/)